# Unable to get custom RKBlockValueTransformer to work properly with RestKit

Tags: ios, swift, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to implement custom value transformers in a RestKit project I'm working on.

I set up my custom first value transformer as follows (Swift):

```
    // Join address components into a single string
    let addressValueTransformer = RKBlockValueTransformer(validationBlock: { (sourceClass, destinationClass) -> Bool in
        return sourceClass.isSubclassOfClass(NSArray.self) && destinationClass.isSubclassOfClass(NSString.self)
        }) { (inputValue, var outputValue, outputValueClass, error) -> Bool in

            let address = inputValue as NSArray
            let formattedAddress = address.componentsJoinedByString(", ")
            outputValue.memory = formattedAddress

            return true
    }
```

If I then add this to the `defaultValueTransformer()`, it doesn't work. Even the `validationBlock` is never called, which is a mystery. The validation block doesn't get called whether I add it to the end of the array of transformers, or at the beginning.

However, if I manually specify the `valueTransformer` property on the `RKAttributeMapping`, I can at least get it to work:

```
    let addressMapping = RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: "location.formattedAddress", toKeyPath: "address")
    addressMapping.valueTransformer = addressValueTransformer
    placeMapping.addPropertyMapping(addressMapping)
```

However, I now want to add a second value transformer, this time on a one-to-one relationship with another object, and it's turning out to be an absolute nightmare...

For some reason, setting the `valueTransformer` on an `RKRelationshipMapping` (as opposed to `RKAttributeMapping` above), has no effect. And as I already mentioned, installing it as a generic value transformer seems to have no effect either, which is evidenced by the fact the `validationBlock` is never even called.

Perhaps I'm missing something critical about how value transformers work, but I wrote the following to test if I can get any value transformer's `validationBlock` to be called:

```
    let testValueTransformer = RKBlockValueTransformer(validationBlock: { (sourceClass, destinationClass) -> Bool in
        println("*** validationBlock ***")
        return true
        }) { (inputValue, var outputValue, outputValueClass, error) -> Bool in
            println("*** transform ***")
            return true
    }

    RKValueTransformer.defaultValueTransformer().insertValueTransformer(testValueTransformer, atIndex: 0)
    RKValueTransformer.defaultValueTransformer().addValueTransformer(testValueTransformer)
```

Based on my understanding, this should definitely be called for **every** value transformation, yet the `validationBlock` is not called once.

What's going wrong here? Is it something to do with my use of Swift (I already had to ensure my objects explicitly subclass `NSObject`...)?

Why are the `validationBlock`s never being called for custom value transformers?

And why doesn't setting `valueTransformer` on `RKRelationshipMapping` have any effect?

The RestKit documentation is unfortunately rather lacking when it comes to advanced use of custom value transformers...

Comment: When are you installing your value transformer? What does trace logging say it's doing when it tries to coerce your received data to the destination object?

Comment: In my case, "validationBlock" is called. The problem could be due to the podfile configuration. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880337/restkit-valuetransformer-not-being-called)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently and found that it was because I added the transform after I added the mappings. Once I added it before the mappings the transform got called.